# Are the human placenta chorionic villi and villous tree the synonyms?

Tags: human-anatomy, terminology, embryology, tissue, microarray

Are the human placental [chorionic villi](http://europepmc.org/abstract/MED/19027158) and the [villous tree](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2710868/) the synonyms? Or, if not, can I say that these tissues would have practically the same gene expression profile in an RNA microarray experiment?